# 2T(n/2) +n by induction

Tags: induction, recursion

I try to proof by induction that:

$$ T(n)= 2 T(n/2)+n \quad n>2,\quad T(2)=2,\quad n = 2^{k}$$

is 
$$ n*lg_2(n) $$

How can I do this?

Thanks

Steps that i went throw:

==Base Case==
$$T(2) = 2, \quad 2\cdot lg(2) = 2, \quad$$
My base case is verified

==Induction Step ==

Inductive hypothesis

$$ 2T((n+1)/2) +(n+1) = (n+1)\cdot lg_2(n+1)$$

I'm stuck here...

Comment: Hi!  To help get the best possible answers, you should explain where you are confused.  Do you understand what induction is, and just don't know how to apply it to this particular problem, or is there something else you're stuck on?

Comment: Also, here are some hints for typing math: you can use `\cdot` for multiplication' and `\lg` or `\log_2` for the binary logarithm.

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are confused is that (if I understand your problem correctly) $T(n)$ is defined only for $n = 2^k$, i.e. only when $n$ is a power of two.

Often when you do induction, you assume the statement is true for $n$, and then prove it is true for $n + 1$.  But here, $T$ isn't even *defined* for $n + 1$ because it is *only defined for powers of two*.  So you're going to have to be more clever.

You don't have to worry about $n + 1$ because it's not a power of two.  What you *do* have to worry about is all the powers of two.  So the way you would prove this by induction is, assuming it is true for $n$, *prove it is true **for the next power of two***.

Letting $n = 2^k$, the next power of two is $2^{k+1}$.  Therefore, you're going to want to assume that
$$
T(n) = n \log_2 ( n ) \quad \textbf{for } \textbf{n = } \textbf{2}^\textbf{k}
$$
and prove that
$$
T(n) = n \log_2 (n) \quad \textbf{for } \textbf{n = } \textbf{2}^\textbf{k + 1}.
$$

Comment: Would it be more easy to change all the "n" in the formula by "2^k" and "2^(k+1)"

Comment: @gspfranc yes.  In fact, that is basically what the problem is asking you to do, since $T(n)$ is only defined for $n = 2^k$.  If you like, you can define a new function $F(k) = T(2^k)$ for all $k$ and deal with that function instead.